# how to get current date and time in jaggery js?

Tags: wso2, jaggery-js, wso2-identity-server

I am working in wso2 data analytical server. I'm using query to get data based on timestamp but I have given time stamp manually. Please tell me how to get current date and time together in milliseconds in jaggery js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var currentDate = new Date();
Math.round(Date.parse(currentDate) / 1000);
var end = Date.parse(currentDate) // Converting in Timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call java within jaggery. So these should work.

```
var milis = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();
var date = new java.util.Date().toString();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I have used above code. @Bhathiya